# excel if cell contains then matching value then copy adjacent cell

Tags: excel

I am looking for a simple IF statement that will allow me to compare two columns, and if they match, to copy the value from a third column into a new cell.

EG: 
Columns 1 and 3 contain names with column 2 containing value for the column 1 name. If column 3 name matches column 1 name I would like the associated value from column 2 to be pasted into a new cell.

```
Column 1    Column2 Column3
ACAN        7       ADNP
ADNP        4       AHR  
AMER        3       ACAN
```

Result I would like:

```
Column 1    Column2  Column3 Column 4    
ACAN         7       ADNP     4    
ADNP         4       AHR      0    
AMER         3       ACAN     7
```

I have the following formula working:

```
if(isnumber(D1:KY1=B:B,A:A,D3)
```

but this just takes the first value found in column A - not the value I need depending on the cell with the correct name.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP() for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following formula into cell D1 and drag down:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$3,0)),0)
```

The `IFERROR` is used to populate the cell with 0 if no match is found.

[image]

Comment: Glad it is working, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Once someone has answered your question, you should mark that answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Did you add more rows? To check all of the rows (not just the first three) you could change the formula to: `= IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(C1,$A:$A,0)),0)`.